# Single git command to localize all remote branches

Tags: git

I want to create local branches for each remote branch

[image: git branches]

If I have 100 branches, it will not be practical.

So I do:

```
git branch -r
```

To see the list of all remote branches and create the following commands

```
git checkout -b AAAAA --no-track origin/AAAAA
git checkout -b BBBBB --no-track origin/BBBBB
git checkout -b CCCCC --no-track origin/CCCCC
git checkout -b DDDDD --no-track origin/DDDDD
...
```

It does all I need. But if I have 100 projects, it is still a tedious task.

Is there any single git command that does this job automatically for me?

Note: The option `--no-track` is very vital for me. This is because the repositories are converted from svn to git. So, connecting to origin is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this, assuming it's `origin`:

```
git branch -r | grep origin | sed 's/.*origin\///' | while read branch; do
    git checkout -b $branch --no-track origin/$branch
done
```

Or, taking advantage of the way git stores remote references:

```
ls -1 .git/refs/remotes/origin/ | while read branch; do
    git checkout -b $branch --no-track origin/$branch
done
```

Comment: Careful with your `ls -1 .git/refs/...` suggestion : `git gc` will call `git pack-refs` (configurable but active by default), which will remove individual files under `refs/` and pack them in one signle `.git/packed-refs` file. See [`git help pack-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs) and its activation when running [`git help gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt-gcpackRefs).

Comment: If you want to list remote branches from your local filesystem, you will have to combine the two approaches (`ls .git/refs/remotes/origin | ...` and `cat .git/packed-refs | grep refs/remotes/origin | ...`)

Comment: Also : it should be a recursive `ls`, and you should list only files (not directories). `find .git/refs/remotes/origin -type f` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Great catch. Assumed single level. Will correct one day? Perhaps! :)